# Kubernetes NodePort url getting changed with "minikube service <service>"

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube, darwin

I have created a NodePort to forward request from port `30101->80->8089`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gorest-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: gorest
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8089
      nodePort: 30101
```

When I try to get the service URL `http://192.168.49.2:30101`, I am unable to access it, but with url `http://127.0.0.1:64741`, retrieved by using `minikube service <service>`, I am able to access.

**Query**: Unable to understand how `http://192.168.49.2:30101` was changed to `http://127.0.0.1:64741` retrived by `minikube service <service>`

```
 % minikube service gorest-service
|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME      | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | gorest-service |        8089 | http://192.168.49.2:30101 |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service gorest-service.
|-----------|----------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME      | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | gorest-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:64741 |
|-----------|----------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/gorest-service in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

Comment: nodeport assignes a random high port number. Afaik you cannot use a fixed port number.

Comment: @TheFool See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) - **by default** yes, kubernetes assigns random port from range `30000-32767`, however you can specify an exact port to be allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct, service exposed using `NodePort` should be reachable on `minikube_IP:NodePort`. First I checked it on Linux VM with minikube installed and it worked.

Then I noticed you're using `MacOS`:

> Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin

Which leads us to some limitations with minikube running with docker driver on MacOS. Please see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193#issuecomment-826331511).

There are two options at least (more, but these are simple to do):

- use `minikube tunnel` what you did and it worked for you.

[Tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/) is used to expose the service from inside of VM where minikube is running to the host machine's network. Please refer to [access applications in minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/). This is how `minikube_IP:NodePort` transforms to `localhost:different_port`.

- start minikube with VirtualBox driver to get a proper IP (if you really need to access your service on `NodePort`), below the command how to start it with VirtualBox driver (this should be installed on your machine):

`minikube start --driver=VirtualBox`

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you remap the service port *inside* the container from port 80 to port 8089.

If you want to access that service *inside* kubernetes you have to use the 8089 port.

*BUT* you cannot access services inside K8s from the outside world: you need to expose them (you should use a load balancer or an egress service).

Minikube is meant to be used for development. The 64741 port you see is a tunnel service that starts minikube and allows you to test and debug your service outside k8s without using an egress (which might be doing more than just connecting the service with the outside world, like for instance authenticating or authorizing requests).